# Call php query with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

my Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com/test.php"></script>
```

the javascript is for a multidomain use , it must be like this it **can't** be changed

i need to make the javascript call the php with the host url as query

location.hostname

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com/test.php?*location.hostname*"></script>
```

what will need to put in the javascript ???
i know what to put in the php

Comment: Put this `alert('I will have learned the javascript basics **before** I ask next question');` and run - there will be an answer for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're not trying to get the string "location.hostname", right? You want the actual hostname from the URL?  in that case you have to write the script include as a document.write.

```
document.write("<script language='javascript' src='http://test.com/test.php?q=" + location.hostname + "'><\/script>");
```

Something like that... WHY are you doing this?

Comment: well... that would depend on what you have IN your test.php. Don't forget that the javascript interpeter is trying to read what it gets there as javascript! You haven't answered the question though... why are you doing this? This is a really terrible way to solve this problem.